# Cross Compile Linux Kernel Module

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, cross-compiling, kernel-module

I am looking into cross compiling a kernel module for an ARM linux. I have my toolchain installed. 
But there's something I am not quite getting from various how-tos.
The module I want to build is `gadgetfs`.

The kernel version on my host is `3.5.0-34-generic` while 
 on the target it's `3.6.9-0.1`

Now what kernel sources or headers do I actually need to download and install, and where?
I downloaded `linux-3.6.9.tar.bz2` from `kernel.org` and extracted it.
In `drivers/usb/gadget/` there's a `Makefile` and according to this site I need to append these lines to it, then run `make`:

```
KDIR := /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build
PWD := `pwd`
obj-m := dummy_hcd.o gadgetfs.o
default: 
$(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
```

But what do i have to replace `uname -r` with? Cause this would give me my host's kernel version. But my target version is different. Where is the `/lib/modules/3.6.9` folder?
`CROSS_COMPILE` and `ARCH` is both set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cross compile (or download pre-compiled) matching version of Linux for your target on your host machine with right configuration since Linux doesn't have a [stable binary API](http://www.kroah.com/log/linux/stable_api_nonsense.html). Host's kernel version is not relevant.

After having target build available on your host you can build a module via

```
make -C kernel_build_dir M=`pwd` ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=<...> modules
```

under that module's directory.